# Editting randomly sampled subset of an indexed subset in R?

Tags: r, random, indexing

I have a question about indexing and editing data structures in R.  For instance, suppose I have a data frame `myDF`:

```
myDF=data.frame(a=rep(c(1,2),10), b=rep(0,20), c=rep(0,20), d=rep(0,20))
```

I know that I can use column `a` to index other columns and edit them like this:

```
myDF$b[myDF$a==1]=3
```

And I know I can use `sample()` to get 5 cells at random from a column and edit them like this:

```
myDF$c[sample(1:20,5)]=6
```

But how can I select a specific number of cells at random from among those selected based on another column, for editing purposes?  E.g. what if I want to set the value of 5 random cells from `d` to 4 with the constraint that all of these cells also be from rows in which `a==1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `sample` and subsetting like his :

```
myDF$d[sample(which(myDF$a==1),5)]<-4
```

`which` selects the rows that fit the condition, then `sample` just select five of them and you update these rows d value.